# Google Sheets: OnEdit match and clear script

Tags: google-sheets

I wish to create an "onEdit" function that clears cells (Col L to Col O) from a row, if a cell value in Col L is not matching a cell in Col A.

```
Col A = "ID"
Col L = "ID Match"
```

Col A to Col K is an imported range.
Col L to Col O is a static range. This static range has an onEdit function that sorts the row based on changes to Col L. It is in sync with Col A.

I am new to Script Editor, so detailed descriptions would definitely be appreciated, if you have the time to help.

I would love to open up the document, but it has sensitive information on it and is too complex to re-write.

Comment: I don't understand what your current `onEdit` is doing: `sorts the row based on changes to Col L`. Also, what does it mean that `It is in sync with Col A`? If I understand you correctly, you want to clear cells (L-O) from a row if the corresponding value in column L doesn't match the corresponding value in column A? What does it have to do with `sorting the rows` and `sync with Col A`?

Comment: I posted an answer. I'm not sure if that's what you wanted, so please let me know if that works for you!

Comment: I will try and test this soon. I think from your comment it may be correct. You are correct that I want to clear cells (L-O). What I am keen to avoid is, for example, deleting cells (L14-O14) if there is a corresponding figure in A15.

Comment: Cells (A-K) are sorted by column A. And cells (L-O) are sorted by Column L. If someone removes a row in the original imported range (which is in Cells A-K), then it will be removed from the sheets data set. This leaves the rest of the data out of sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to keep track of changes in column L, so that if the edited value in column L matches any of the values in column A, the contents from columns `L-O` are cleared.

If that's the case, you can do the following:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var sheetName = "Sheet1" // Name of the sheet to track. Please change accordingly
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var editedValue = range.getValue();
  var colA = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().map(function(row) { 
    return row[0]; // Get array of values in column A
  });
  // Check that the edited sheet is the one you want to track.
  // Check that edited column is L
  // Check that the edited value is not found in column A
  if (sheet.getName() === sheetName && column === 12 && colA.indexOf(editedValue) === -1) {
    sheet.getRange("L" + row + ":O" + row).clearContent();
  }
}
```

#### Note:

`onEdit` triggers only get fired by **user**'s changes. Changes made by the script, or by data imported in any other way, don't fire the edit. If you want to keep track of this, I'd suggest you to make a [time-based trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder) instead.

#### Reference:

- [Range.clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearContent())
- [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)

Comment: It is a good function and acts very close to what I need. But not quite what I’m looking for.

Comment: It currently removes cells that directly correlate (eg, Cell L14 with A14) rather than cells that correlate with anything in the row (eg, Cell L14 is a match to Cell A13, so don’t delete). I would want a deletion when (eg, Cell L14 has no match with anything in Col A).

Comment: OnEdit doesn’t work how I expected. So, deleting a row at the source of the imported range doesn’t seem to count as an edit. Not sure if this means my aims are fundamentally unworkable, or whether there is a way to get around this.

Comment: To help, I have written a TRUE or FALSE formula in Col P.

`=IFS(
COUNTIF($A$3:$A,$L3)=1,TRUE,
$L3="","",
COUNTIF($A$3:$A,$L3)=0,FALSE,
COUNTIF($A$3:$A,$L3)>1,"ERROR")'

So with this formula, I'd only need a solution to delete Cells (L-P) based on a change (to FALSE) in Col P.

Comment: @AdamHurrell I updated my answer so that columns L to O are deleting if edited value in L matches **any** value in column A. Also, `onEdit` triggers only track changes made by a user, so changes in the imported data (column A) won't fire it. I made a suggestion to fix that (time-based triggers). If that's a good workaround for you but you need more help concerning this, please let me know.

Comment: It is still not working as expected. It should be deleting if Cell L doesn't match any value in Col A. If I enter a new value in Col L that does match, it is deleting the row. I'm going to have a play around with it, because I get that the info I'm giving you isn't the greatest.

Comment: @AdamHurrell Are you sure you have copied the updated code snippet exactly as I posted it? I tested this before posting and I tested it just now. It is deleting the row only if there is no value in column A that matches the value in L. If it matches any of the values, it's not deleting them. Please double-check this.

Comment: I think what I will do, as you have educated me, is do an onChange function based on a FALSE output in the new Col P. I will try and leverage the solution you have provided, as it is so close. Your solution also shows me what I need to learn, so even though it isn't spot on, it is a great help.

Comment: I will doublecheck and run again

Comment: @AdamHurrell `onChange` has the same problem as an `onEdit` (changes that are not made by a user are not tracked).

Comment: @AdamHurrell If you're still having this behaviour, I would suggest you to share a sanitized copy of the spreadsheet so that I can troubleshoot this. We are talking about a fairly easy thing for the script to do.

Comment: Your solution is actually perfect. Thank you. It wasn't a copying issue, rather my manual testing. I wasn't being case sensitive. Thank you so much. I recognise that not opening the document makes it a lot more difficult. Thank you!!

Comment: I will explore the time stamp solution too. Thank you for everything. And I really appreciate the education side of this, so I didn't go and waste my time on onChange, etc.

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." - I have given you an up vote and a tick on the solution. But it doesn't display, due to my level. Thanks again for everything.

Comment: @AdamHurrell You're most welcome. I'm glad I could be helpful.